# Learning JavaScript, jQuery & JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My goal is to present a certain total value of everything under a field of a table in a grid based on specific conditions like date range.

here's what I did to capture the date range from two input fields:

```
<input type="date" id="startdate"/>
<input type="date" id="enddate"/>

var dateArray = '[$('#startdate').val(),$('#enddate').val()]';
var dateJSON = JSON.stringify(dateArray);
```

Now my problem is my on my first JSON script. It's not presenting what it should on the grid column where it should.

```
  {
  "Type": "condition",
  "Data": {
    "Type": "And",
    "Expressions": [{
      "Type": "compare",
      "Data": {
        "Type": "GreaterThan",
        "Left": {
          "Type": "field",
          "Data": {
            "Table": "table",
            "Field": "date"
          }
        },
        "Right": {
          "Type": "constant",
          "Data": "dateArray"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "Type": "compare",
      "Data": {
        "Type": "LessThanOrEqual",
        "Left": {
          "Type": "field",
          "Data": {
            "Table": "table",
            "Field": "date"
          }
        },
        "Right": {
          "Type": "constant",
          "Data": "dateArray"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

Anything that could help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove the wrapping single quotes in your `dateArray` declaration, like this:  `var dateArray = [$('startdate'),$('enddate')];`

Comment: It's an element. Thanks for noticing. I forgot to put # & val() on them but it still isn't working.

Comment: No, I meant the single quotes surrounding your array declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right, it just need a little fix. The right syntax for declaring an array is:

> var arr = [value1, value2, ...]

```js
$('#run').click(function () {
    var dateArray = [$('#startdate').val(), $('#enddate').val()];
    var dateJSON = JSON.stringify(dateArray);
    alert(dateJSON);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="startdate" />
<input type="date" id="enddate" />
<button id="run">Run</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! My only problem now is the JSON arguments